# pydev remote debugging blocks when running to completion

Tags: pydev

I'm following these instructions to remotely debug a python script http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html
Using breakpoints and stepping work without a problem, but after resuming the script (without any other further breakpoints) the script executes the remaining instructions, and then hangs instead of exiting normally. Even closing the server from pydev does not help, I have to Ctrl+Break the script
I am sure I've done this a while ago with an older eclipse+pydev, and the script resumed and exited normally (and it's very important for me not to mess the rest of the execution).

I've tried this with both Eclipse Luna and Liclipse pydev_4.0.0.201504132356, pydev_4.0.0.201504092214 on Windows 7 x64, same behaviour

Is this an intended behavior or a bug? How could I make pydev let the script end normally?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this here... please report that as a bug adding details on how to reproduce it (i.e.: ideally, create a project on github and add a step-by-step on how to reproduce it so that it can be fixed... without being able to reproduce it properly, it may be pretty hard to fix).

Also, please give details on the OS and Python version used in the report (https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/)

Comment: Submitted ticket with bug reproduced on Windows Virtual PC